# Modify .htm files on wireless router

Tags: wireless-router, filezilla

**What am I trying to do?**

I am attempting to access the .htm files on my wireless router to modify the look and feel of the Netgear GENIE webpage(s).

**What have I done?**

I've read several articles on eHow and Instructables that detail how to setup your router as an FTP server, since I figured the best way to access the files would be through FileZilla.  Setting up an FTP server through my router doesn't sound like what I should do to accomplish my task... or perhaps it is?

I've also read the documents provided by Netgear for getting started and setting up functionality on the router.  Maybe I overlooked something?

**My specifications**

- [Netgear router WNR2000v3](http://support.netgear.com/product/WNR2000v3)
- [FileZilla v3.8.1](https://filezilla-project.org/)

**UPDATE**:

Since someone voted to close this question I'll clarify what I'm asking for...

- At the present I am dissatisfied with the current UI/webpage look when logging into routerlogin.net.
- Furthermore I would like to make changes to the admin dashboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to change the router's web configuration interface. The web pages you see when you are configuring your router are served by the router itself and is part of its firmware.

No FTP software will allow you to connect to your router's internal web server and modify these files. It just doesn't work that way.

The only way I can think of that **might** work is if you could find the firmware for your router, somehow manage to decrypt and decompile it, edit the assets (resources like CSS, JS, HTML, etc.) and recompile it back into the format used for firmware upgrades by your router. You **could** then flash this modded firmware to achieve what you want and it **might** just work.

However, I'll assume you wouldn't possibly want to go to all that trouble just so you could see some pretty graphics on the router configuration page so I'll advise you to either stick with the interface that your router currently uses (what good does a pretty router interface do anyway? You won't use it everyday) or if it's such an eyesore, you might want to consider flashing [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) or [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/) on your router.

P.S. I checked, your router [is compatible with DD-WRT firmware](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=260964&view=previous&sid=d8a17c17957e5cedaad4f7693a425e63) but as James2k from the DD-WRT forum puts it, `WNR2000v3 is a bastard child router`.

Comment: Your understanding is correct.  This is mostly for the sake of education, especially since I had a hunch that accomplishing this task would be troublesome.  I just figured the UI would be a good place to start and then work my way down through the levels of abstraction - at least that form of education works for me.  Thank you for the detailed explanation.